# Any way to power on an external HDD without re-plugging it?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hdd, disk, disk-management

I use a 4TB external HDD on daily basis, it's almost always connected to my computer. but whenever I don't need it **On**, I spin it down using **Powe Off This Disk** option in the *Disks Utility*.

[image: Disk Utility with option to "Power off this disk"]

But there is no option to **Power it on**. all one can do is Re-plug it or Reboot the computer both of which are pretty hard options in my case.

Is their any other way to turn on the External HDD like we can do with internal Drives?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to mount the partition which will power it on. Or use the "standby" option, which will power it down but leave it accessible. When you need to use it again just mount the partition. The little play button under the volumes bar will mount it.

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer. but after powering the drive off. it disappears from Nautilus, So I'm unable to mount it